# How can I convert from EUREF-FIN coords to Lat/Long?

Tags: coordinate-system

See question title, how can I translate [EUREF-FIN](http://www.kolumbus.fi/eino.uikkanen/geodocsgb/ficoords.htm) coords to Lat Long?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.kolumbus.fi/eino.uikkanen/geodocsgb/ficoords.htm:

> In Finland projection ETRS-TM35 is used country wide and is therefore called ETRS-TM35FIN, where FIN is for the non-standard zone width.

ETRS-TM35 equals **EPSG:3067** and Lat/Lon WGS84 is EPGS:4326

Coordinate re-projection can be performed on command line level e.g. using [gdaltransform](http://gdal.org/gdaltransform.html) or using a GUI like QGIS "Save as ...":

[image]